# How can I POST json or the contents of an object using Scribe?

Tags: java, oauth, scribe

I'm using Jackson to serialize a model into json, and I'd like to make a POST request with that model to a url using Scribe, an OAuth java library.

Currently I'm creating the service with a util method, creating the request for that service, then I sign the request then send it. I need to somehow attach my object along with the request before sending.

```
final OAuth20Service service = util.getService();
final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, url, service);
// request.addPayload(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(requestModel));
// request.addParameter(???);
service.signRequest(new OAuth2AccessToken(accessToken), request);
final Response postResponse = request.send();
```

The problem is that sending the stringified json as a payload isn't working, and the only way to set a parameter is by passing in two strings, but my object has nested arrays and objects inside of it. Since `postResponse.getBody()` returns a string (I'm assuming in json), it must support sending json the other way, right? How can I send complex parameters (e.g. an object model, json, etc) along with the request?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `application/json;charset=UTF-8` content type.

```
final OAuth20Service service = util.getService();
final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, url, service);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
request.addPayload(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(requestModel));
// or this if you have a json string
// request.addPayload(json);
service.signRequest(new OAuth2AccessToken(accessToken), request);
final Response postResponse = request.send();
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the request without having the consumer token? Like when you make the first request to get the access and secret tokens

Comment: @Bradley from which package we need to import Mapper?